# Given variable to graphlql query returns undefined (object Object)

Tags: typescript, graphql

I try to perform a simple graphql query (Hello World) with an input variable. I give an input but it is recognized as undefined or [object Object].

I already tried different versions of Code, but I'm new to TypeScript and Graphql, so nothing worked. I also tried toString.

**graphql schema:**

```
type Query{
    helloName(name:String): String
}
```

**resolver:**

```js
Query: {
   helloName: (_:any, name:string) => `Hello ${name}`
}
```

**graphql query:**

```
query helloName($name: String){
  helloName(name:$name)
}
```

**query variables:**

```
{"name":"Max"}
```

**actual result:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "helloName": "Hello[object Object]"
  }
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "helloName": "Hello Max"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter passed to a resolver is an object representing the arguments for the field being resolved. Each property in the object maps to an argument, as long as it was actually provided -- so a field with no arguments will just receive an empty object.

So, your resolver should look more like this:

```
helloName: (_, args) => `Hello ${args.name}`
```